# Render Layers node does not have output for vector pass

Tags: compositing-nodes

I'm trying to render speed vectors along with image and depth. So, I've enabled 'vector pass' in `View Layer Properties > Passes`. However, in compositor, I'm not getting an output node for vector. I've attached screenshots below. The same procedure works for most blend files, but is not working for this specific blend file. Is there some setting that needs to be changed?

[image]
[image]

PS: Unfortunately, I can't share the blend file here.

Comment: It looks like it's not the same render layer, you have RenderLayer.001 selected on the left, and RenderLayer on the right

Comment: Thanks! Good catch.